# SQL query and preg_match

Tags: php, sql, preg-match

Need your help with sql query and php.

I have to pieces of code here:
1.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUBSTR(n.`title`, 1,1) FROM node n WHERE n.`type` = 'type1'";
$results = db_query($sql);
while ($fields = db_fetch_array($results)) {
  foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

The code above returns first letters of my article titles (table - node, columns - type, title) like this - NHDKFLF...

2.

```
if (preg_match ('/A/i', $string)) {
  echo ('Contains letter A'); //
}
else {
  echo ('Nothing'); //
}
```

And the second part checks if the string contains certain letters.

Now, the question is how to combine these two pieces of code? I mean how to pull data from DB and check if it has certain letters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:  Do what you're doing now, or re-write the SQL to do both at once.

Option 1:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUBSTR(n.`title`, 1,1) FROM node n WHERE n.`type` = 'type1'";
$results = db_query($sql);
while ($fields = db_fetch_array($results)) {
  foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match ('/A/i', $value)) {
       echo ('Contains letter A'); //
    } else {
       echo ('Nothing'); //
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUBSTR(n.`title`, 1,1) FROM node n WHERE n.`type` = 'type1' AND SUBSTR(n.`title`, 1,1) = 'A' ";
```

Depending on the rest of the details of your project there is probably a better way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the first option and it returns something like:
NothingNothingNothingNothing... Contains letter A... NothingNothing...  
That's why I wanted to separate my sql part and get somehow (if it's possible) one string with first letters. After that try to check if that string has certain letters like:
    if (preg_match ('/A/i', $value)) {
        ...
    if (preg_match ('/B/i', $value)) {
        ...

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just query for the ones you want?

```
... where SUBSTR(n.`title`, 1,1) = 'A' ...
```

If you must filter in your code, outside the query, then:

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match ('/A/i', $value)) {
        ...
}
```